# Array won't convert to XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I have this array ($data):

```
Array (
    [status_code] => X
    [key_1] => 12345
    [key_2] => 67890
    [short_message] => test
    [long_message] => test_long_message
)
```

But I am struggling to convert this to an XML element.

Here is my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Here is the results I am wanting:

```
<root>
    <status_code>X</status_code>
    <key_1>12345</key_1>
    <key_2>67890</key_2>
    <short_message>test</short_message>
    <long_message>test_long_message</long_message>
</root>
```

Instead I get:

```
<X>1234567890testtest_message_long
```

Could somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleXMLElement.addChild()](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.addchild) takes its parameters in the order `$elementName, $elementValue`.

[array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) passes the elements in the order `$value, $key` (in your example that would be `$elementValue, $elementName`).

This should work:

```
$data = array(
    'status_code' => 'X',
    'key_1' => 12345
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive(
    $data,
    function ($value, $key) use ($xml) {
        $xml->addChild($key, $value);
    }
);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: I am still getting the same output as before?

Comment: Sorry, it is slightly different from before. Here I am getting: <X>1234567890testtest_message_long

Comment: If I run my code sample above in a test setup, I get "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><status_code>X</status_code><key_1>12345</key_1></root>" as output, which seems like what you're looking for. You can verify this on a PHP sandbox site like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ . Perhaps you are looking at the output in a browser? A browser will ignore any tags it does not understand.

Comment: I see! I am using a browser! I thought XML could be viewed in a browser!

Comment: @PeterStuart: it can be, but you need to tell the browser what you're doing (for example by writing an [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for your XML document), otherwise it's going to assume it received HTML and then ignore tags like `<status_code>` since those don't exist in HTML. To view exactly what the browser received from the server, you can use the "View page source" option in the right-click menu of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it out, it's much easier to read and change:

```
foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    $xml->$name = $value;
}
```

It's not always necessary to just have a callback when a simple foreach can do. Howver, creating a utility function isn't that bad either:

```
function simplexml_add_array(SimpleXMLElement $xml, array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        $xml[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

And then finally by inheritence ([Demo](https://eval.in/58453)):

```
class SimplerXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function addArray(array $data) {
        foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }
}


$xml = new SimplerXMLElement ('<root/>');
$xml->addArray($data);
print $xml->asXML();
```

Program Output (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <status_code>X</status_code>
  <key_1>12345</key_1>
  <key_2>67890</key_2>
  <short_message>test</short_message>
  <long_message>test_long_message</long_message>
</root>
```